# Fourier transform between four-vector $\bf{X}$ and four-wave vector $\bf{K}$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, momentum, fourier-transform

I want to know what is Fourier transform (of wave function) between $\bf{X}$ (four-vector) and $\bf{K}$ (four-wave vector)?

and also

I need to know what is the difference between Fourier transform between $\bf{X}$ (four-wave vector) and $\bf{K}$ (four-wave vector), and Fourier transform between $\bf{x}$ (three-vector) and $\bf{k}$ (three-wave vector)?

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\vect}[1]{{\bf #1}}$

In general, in $n$-dimensions if $f = f(\vect{x})$, $\vect{x}
 = (x_1,\cdots,x_n)$ then you can define its Fourier transform as

$$
\mathcal{F}[f](\vect{p}) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}{\rm d}\vect{x}~ f(\vect{x})e^{-2\pi i \vect{x}\cdot\vect{p}} = 
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}{\rm d}x_1\cdots {\rm d}x_n f(x_1,\cdots, x_n)e^{-2\pi i(x_1 p_1 +\cdots + x_np_n) }
$$

and

$$
\mathcal{F}^{-1}[F](\vect{x}) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}{\rm d}\vect{p}~F(\vect{p})e^{2\pi i \vect{x}\cdot\vect{p}} = 
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}{\rm d}p_1\cdots {\rm d}p_n F(p_1,\cdots, p_n)e^{2\pi i(x_1 p_1 +\cdots + x_np_n) }
$$

Comment: Normalization constant? Should the minus be in both integrals?

Comment: @Emil I meant the wave function

Comment: @Okalki: ? Better to ask caverac, I just thought the integrals looked suspect in the original version.